# Rendering htm tag in C#

Tags: c#, html, rendercontrol

Hi and thanks in advance for reading.

Recently, I upgraded my application from .net2 to .net 4.5. Everything works fine except the top htm control

```
"<html runat="server" id="pageHtm">
```

Running the appplication, I get this weird parser error:

```
The base class includes the field 'pageHtml', but its type (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlElement) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl).
```

After a lot of tries, I got that this is a known bug and the solution is a patch by Microsoft. However, the problem still exists even after installing the patch.

Comment: Please add your code, so we can have a look

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this problem, follow these steps:

1. open the PageName.aspx.designer.cs file.

Note The placeholder PageName represents the name of the Web page on which you encounter the problem.

2.Locate the entries for the **tbody**, **thead**, and **tfoot** tags.

3.Change the entries to map these tags to the new classes. For example, make the following

changes.

Old entry

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl tbodyname;
```

New entry

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableBodySection tbodyname;
```

Save the PageName.aspx.designer.cs file.

To automatically resolve this problem by using the Visual Studio designer, follow these steps:

1.In Visual Studio open the PageName.aspx file.

Note The placeholder PageName represents the name of the Web page on which you encounter the problem.

2.In the Source window, locate the  and  tags, and then select all entries in the range that includes these tags.

3.On the **Edit** menu, click **Cut**. This operation removes the corresponding entries from the PageName.aspx.designer.cs file.

Keep the cursor in the same location.

4.On the **Edit** menu, click **Paste**. This operation adds the entries that inherit the new classes back to the PageName.aspx.designer.cs file.

Save the PageName.aspx file.

**Answer above is a general solution but your case**

open your designer file of your page in solution explorer and change all of

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlElement
```

to

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl
```